Epsilon delta definition of limits. Discussion for finding delta
I've seen some proofs where they set a value of delta (it's usually 1), then they find an expression for delta in terms of epsilon, and finally delta is chosen as the minimum between that expression and the number.
Now, I wanted to discuss other ways to approach these problems.
Example: $$\lim_{x \to -1} (x^2-2x+3)=6$$
After we work over the definition we get $$|x+1||x-3|<\epsilon$$
Now, considering $|x+1|<\delta$ we can write $$-\delta<x+1<\delta$$
$$-\delta-4<x-3<\delta-4$$ $$-(\delta+4)<x-3<\delta-4<\delta+4$$
And then $$|x-3|<\delta+4\implies |x+1||x-3|<\delta(\delta+4)$$
So, we can write $$\delta(\delta+4)=\epsilon$$
in order to get an expression for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. We can solve the quadratic equation considering the positive solution:$$\delta^2+4\delta-\epsilon=0\implies\delta=-2+\sqrt{4+\epsilon}>0$$
I would like to know what you think about this approaching where we find $\delta(\epsilon)$.

This looks right. But it is a rather inefficient way of proving that this specific polynomial is continuous at $x=-1,.$ Much more is true and that is simpler to prove.

oek Cafu, your first sentence is unclear.

Sure, this works. The $\text{min}\left{1,\frac{\epsilon}{M}\right}$ approach is going to be more broadly applicable. The important thing to pay attention to is the principle behind that approach: That is, when you can't uniformly bound a function you sometimes have to settle for bounding it near the limit point. This is perfectly acceptable because all that matters when taking a limit is the behavior of the function NEAR the limit point anyways.

In this kind of problem, I always advise to transform the convergence to a random point $x\to -1$ by a convergence $u\to 0$.
Indeed rewrite $|x+1|<\delta\quad$ by $\quad\begin{cases}x=-1+u\\|u|<\delta\end{cases}$
$|(x^2-2x+3)-6|=|u^2-4u|\le\underbrace{|u|}_{\to\ 0}\times\underbrace{|u-4|}_\text{bounded}\to 0$

for $\delta=\varepsilon$ then $|u|<\varepsilon$
for $\delta=1$ then  $|u-4|<5$

(i.e. $-1<u<1\implies -5<u-4<-3\implies |u-4|<5$)
So by taking $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$ then $|u|<\delta\implies |(x^2-2x+3)-6|<5\varepsilon$
If you want it aesthetic, you can refine to $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}5)$ to get $|\cdot|<\varepsilon$

Note :
You can also proceed using this alternate method which uses the inequality $$|u|<1\implies |u|^k<\cdots<|u|^3<|u|^2<|u|$$
Therefore you don't need to solve $\delta^2+4\delta=\varepsilon$ instead proceed like this :
$|u^2-4u|\le|u^2|+|-4u|\le|u|^2+4|u|\le|u|+4|u|\le5|u|$
and end up with the same conclusion than before.
Similarly would you have nasty powers of $u$, just ignore them, for instance
$|u^4+5u^2-7u^2-4u|\le (1+5+7+4)|u|\le 17|u|$ and you just need to take $\delta=\min(1,\frac\epsilon{17})$
This is the reason why we take this min with $1$, to ensure $|u|<1$ and be able to do this simplification $|u|^k<|u|$
